# Multiplying 3 bit number using 4 bit full adder

Tags: digital-logic, adder, circuit-design

So I'm trying to design a circuit where a 3 bit input can be multiplied by a constant value, for instance 6.

And I'm trying to implement this using a 4 bit adder which generate a 5 bit binary number but I'm not quite sure how to get started.

I've written the truth table for the outputs and the only pattern I can observe thus far is that the 1 values tend to shift to the left.

Eg. 000 => 00000, 001 => 00110, 010 => 01100, 011 => 10010

Any help or advice would be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you were to multiply the largest 3 bit number 111 (ie 7) by another 3 bit number 111 (ie 7) [you haven't specified how larger the second number could be] you get 7x7 = 49 which in binary is 11 0001 which is 6 bits... How are you expecting only 5?

Comment: I'm not multiplying a 3 bit number with another 3 bit number. I'm multiplying a 3 bit number with a constant value. So 1 x 6 = 6, 2 x 6 = 12, 3 x 6 = 18 and etc.

Comment: @UnholyWish - Your constant has to be expressed as a number in some number of bits. It takes three bits to represent your constant 6. So by the time you get up to 4x6, 5x6, 6x6 or even 7x6 you are multiplying two three bit numbers! And case in point with regard to the output number of bits to hold the result when you get to 6x6 the will be taking 6 bits to hold the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are multiplying with exactly 6, then the following works:

Input \$X\$, three bits.
Shift \$X\$ one position to the left and add with \$X\$. $$2X + X \Rightarrow 3X$$
Shift the result one position to the left. $$3X \times 2 \Rightarrow 6X$$